Flutter WebView: How to Keep Microphone and Camera Active When App is in Background?
I'm developing a Flutter app that utilizes a WebView to access webpages needing microphone and camera functionality. Everything works fine when the app is in the foreground, but the microphone and camera stop functioning a few seconds after the app goes into the background.
My Requirements:
The microphone and camera must remain accessible through the WebView and the embedded webpages.
Building the functionality natively is not an option for my use case.

Attempts:
I considered using Picture-in-Picture (PiP) mode to keep the app technically in the foreground, but I haven't tried this yet.

Question:
Is there a way to keep the microphone and camera active when the app goes into the background? If Picture-in-Picture mode is a viable solution, how can I implement it in Flutter? Are there any other solutions or workarounds that can help achieve this?
Additional Information:
Flutter version: Flutter 3.22.2
WebView plugin: webview_flutter
Target platforms: iOS/Android or both

Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I'm also facing exactly same issue. Let me know if you have find anything helpful

You can try picture in picture mode, with that it is working in my app!!!

Ashish, finally I'm able to access microphone and camera in background mode by adding foreground microphone and foreground camera permission in manifest

Can provide an explanation and code explaining how you did it?? as i already have provided mic and camera access , and it do work in foreground. But the issue comes when i minimize the app, after 3-5 seconds mic do not record, untilll app goes back to foregroud..
